# warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000008048060

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I keep getting an error message using NASM, i am using an online compiler: compileonline.com
Heres my code. (note this is from another source)

```
    segment .text

    global main
main:

    xor     edx, edx
    mov     eax, 15
    mov     ecx, 3
    div     ecx
    xor     ecx, ecx
    mov     cx, ax
    mov ebx,1       ; arg1, where to write, screen
    mov eax,4       ; write sysout command to int 80 hex
    int 0x80        ; interrupt 80 hex, call kernel



exit:   mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx 
    int 0x80
```

Please explain what I am doing wrong, and the location so I understand.
Here is my output:

```
$nasm -f elf *.asm; ld -m elf_i386 -s -o demo *.o
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000008048060
$demo
```

Comment: Either set the entry point to `main` using a linker switch or change `main` into `_start` which is the default name for the entry point. Even so, your code is broken.

Comment: You didn't link the C start files that call `main`.  If you want to write the ELF entry point, call it `_start`.  It's getting linked that way anyway as a fallback, and then the linker warns you about doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really only in C (and C++) that the starting point is named `main`.

The default linker script usually uses `start` or `_start` for the actual entry point. If you rename or add the correct symbol then the linker should not complain about that.

Comment: I tried renaming `main` with `_start` but it still isn't working.

Comment: @DevPlayz you mean you still get warning from linker? Because that should be fixed by the rename. If you mean the binary doesn't do what you expect, then that is correct, that code does make little sense and if it is supposed to write out some integer as result of division, then it needs lot of fixing (the output part). If you are just starting with assembly, consider to use debugger to check values in registers, and don't bother with output at all, outputting something more complex to console is not as simple as in other programming languages, for example integers must be formatted to string.

Comment: I stand corrected. I only renamed one of the “main”s. I kinda suck at assembly. Note this is old me, and I wasn’t sure what worked and what didn’t.